# How to compare values in a loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have orders come in. Each order has a type i.e 'Vanilla' and a size i.e 'Mini with a quantity.

If there are 5 Mini Vanillas I want it to display once not 5 times. I also want to tally the quantity.

Here is one of the many things I attempted

```
$prevSize = null;
$prevType= null;

foreach ($orders as $order){
echo '<tr>';
$new_order = new WC_Order();
    $order_items = $new_order->get_items();

  foreach ($order_items as $order_item ){
  $currentSize = $order_item['pa_size'];
  $currentType = wp_get_post_terms( $order_item['product_id'],'pa_ct');
  $currentType = $currentType[0]->name;

  if($prevSize != $currentSize){
    echo $currentType . '<br>';
    echo $currentSize . '<br>';
  }
    $count += $order_item['qty'];
    echo $count;
 }
  $prevSize = $currentSize;
  $prevType = $currentType;}
```

Comment: Insert `$count` after `$prevType` and assing it a `0`. To concatenate use a dot instead of plus. `$count = 0` | `$count .= $order_item['qty']`

Comment: Why not use an associative array with a unique key that represents the product ("mini_vanilla") and the value that represents the quantity? On each iteration you add the quantity to the array and you display the array after exiting the loops.

Answer (score 0):

We have analyzed your query, and according to your need, here is my solution:

```
$order_type = array();  
foreach ($orders as $order){
  echo '<tr>';  
  $new_order = new WC_Order();
  $order_items = $new_order->get_items();
  $count = 0;
  foreach ($order_items as $order_item ){
    $currentSize = $order_item['pa_size'];
    $currentType = wp_get_post_terms( $order_item['product_id'],'pa_ct');
    $currentType = $currentType[0]->name;
    $temp_order_type = $currentSize.'_'.$currentType;
    if(!in_array($temp_order_type, $order_type)){
       $order_type[] = $temp_order_type;
       echo $currentType . '<br>';
       echo $currentSize . '<br>';
    }
    $count += $order_item['qty'];
  }
  echo $count;
}
```

Above code will display each order type once not display multiple times. And display the quantity ordered in each order.